# Doctrine custom type always altering table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have added a custom type like:

```
namespace My\SuperBundle\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class Money extends Type
{
    const MONEY = 'money';

    public function getSqlDeclaration(
        array $fieldDeclaration,
        AbstractPlatform $platform
    ) {
        return 'DECIMAL(10,2)';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::MONEY;
    }
}
```

And in my application boot:

```
namespace My\SuperBundle;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use My\SuperBundle\Types\Money;

class MyBSuperBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //add custom quantity and wight types
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        if(!Type::hasType(Money::MONEY)) {
            Type::addType(Money::MONEY, 'My\SuperBundle\Types\Money');
        }
    }
}
```

However **every time** I update the database with:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I keep getting the following:

```
ALTER TABLE product_price CHANGE price price DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
```

Apart from that everything works super fine. The fields in the DB are correct.
Is there a reason why doctrine keeps updating with the same data?

Comment: Looks like there's a bug http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-353?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I closed the issue as incomplete because that was not reproducible.

Answer (score 14):

You have to override the method `requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)` and return `true`. Like that, doctrine will remember the custom type.

```
namespace My\SuperBundle\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class Money extends Type
{
    const MONEY = 'money';

    public function getSqlDeclaration(
        array $fieldDeclaration,
        AbstractPlatform $platform
    ) {
        return 'DECIMAL(10,2)';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::MONEY;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Source: [Use column comments for further Doctrine Type Inference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-42)

Answer (score 4):

There's an alternative way to do this using configurations.

config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types: { money: My\SuperBundle\Types\Money }

    connections:
        your_connection_name:
            mapping_types: { money: money }
```

Sources:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types
- https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/103#issuecomment-10083314

Comment: Thanks! Just a note that if you don't use the "connections" section, you can put the "mapping_types" entry directly in the "dbal" section.

Answer (score 3):

You are not telling the DBAL platform about your type, so obviously, the DBAL schema introspection utilities cannot recognize it. To register the type, you can do following:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use My\SuperBundle\Types\Money;

class MyBSuperBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
        $entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        if( ! Type::hasType(Money::MONEY)) {
            Type::addType(Money::MONEY, 'My\SuperBundle\Types\Money');
            $entityManager
                ->getConnection()
                ->getDatabasePlatform()
                ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('decimal', Money::MONEY);
        }
    }
}
```

This should stop the DBAL from complaining about schema differences.

Comment: ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('decimal', Money::MONEY); OR ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('decimal(10,2)', Money::MONEY); ?

Comment: It should be without the specific parametrization.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I have 3 types (Money, Weight and Quantity) all of which result at decimal(10,2) could that be the case? At the boot section I have declared all as decimal as you suggested

Comment: Did you consider using the built-in numeric type instead?

Comment: You mean instead of using decimal or instead of using custom types?

Comment: Instead of using custom types.

Comment: I would want to avoid it, since it is probable that the specs for the money, quantity and weight fields will change sooner or later

Comment: Looks like that I missed "You can only map a database type to exactly one Doctrine type. Database vendors that allow to define custom types like PostgreSql can help to overcome this issue." from http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types so no custom types for now :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ZF2.

I solved it **removing the hyphen** in my custom type name.

Wrong:

```
'doctrine_type_mappings' => [
    'custom-type' => 'custom-type'
],
```

Good:

```
'doctrine_type_mappings' => [
    'customtype' => 'customtype'
],
```

More details about implementation in Zend Framework 2: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/EXTRAS_ORM.md

I hope this can help someone.