# Symfony/Doctrine Rearranging Database Columns

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I go to generate a table using the doctrine:schema:update command line, it appears that Doctrine(or Symfony?) wants to throw in a command that rearranges my columns, putting the keys towards the front it would appear. I was wondering if, and more hopefully, where, I can disable this "feature" of the Environment, so when I go to generate my tables, they are kept in the order which I entered them into the orm.

I've looked around for this problem, but it would seem that no one else has it from what I've been able to come up with, and I'm not certain what bundle/part of Doctrine or Symfony I need to alter to have it not desire to rearrange my tables. Any information as to just what part of the bundle would contain this logic, or what option I can add to alter it would be greatly appreciated, as I'm unable to really find anything in the documentation so far.

**Update:**
I did some investigating, and I found an overflow question similar to mine, but not quite. In my case, I'm NOT using new datatypes, and the only columns moved forward are the ones that I've designated as being keys (Primary, or Foreign). The commands that it throws me looks VERY similar to this, except it's doing it to each and every one of my keys.

```
ALTER TABLE product_price CHANGE price price DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
```

[Doctrine custom type always altering table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661139/doctrine-custom-type-always-altering-table)

**Update 2:** Additional information as requested:
Running MySQL under a .orm.yml format.

The fields it wants to set are always the key fields, and after I change them back to the order I want/need them in, it then feels the need to rearrange the columns again every time.

I don't change anything about the fields; it does this both on initial creations, as well as whenever I need to run the schema update, without any changes to those specific fields.

Comment: I've never seen doctrine insisting on rearranging my columns. What DBMS and version are you using? Is it possible that some details are different between the column and the property mapping, for example if you've changed the precision, nullability or default value?

Comment: Does doctrine:schema:update stop complaining after you've ran the ALTER TABLE statement, or does it keep suggesting the same SQL statement over and over again. What's your mapping configuration (the annotations or .yml structure). In short: More info is needed in order to understand your situation. ;-)

Comment: Added more information to the main question, hopefully it's enough now, if not let me know what else is required and I'll add what I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of digging, and I don't think you can have any control over this. See getColumns() [1] [2]

Judging by this, the order is PK, FK, and other columns, in that order.
It is difficult scanning through pages of raw logic so I may have missed something, but from what I can tell it is not acting on any configuration to decide the order.

[1] (at the time of the answer; Nov 2013) https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/5ffb052a2e622908c988f79e9a099f5d64f40b34/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L555

[2] (updated line number; June 2020) https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.10.x/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L595

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the issue though, as the problem stems from Doctrine adding an ALTER TABLE <table> CHANGE <column> <columnNameAgain> <datatype> ..., and I don't see any lines similar to that in this class. By chance am I missing it from what you linked?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the platform specific classes.  They are where the SQL gets compiled.

Comment: I think your answers combined are the issue. It would seem to me that it's trying to put my Primary Key as my first column, foreign as second, and then it's letting the other columns come as they wish. The problem with this is that the getAlterTableSQL() function in dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php must call that getColumns you mentioned at some point, notice my table isn't in the order it wants, and then attempts to rearrange them according to what it wants for that get Columns.

Comment: Are you saying the column order is different to the order of your entity properties, or the schema update is changing the order of an existing database schema?

Comment: The column order differs from what it inside the ORM. It seems to create them in the order I specify, and then after it comes across and adds the indexes it seems, and after that, it reorders the columns into what it desires, that is, the PKs, followed by FK, followed by general indexes.

Comment: It is just hard coded to do it that way, they must not have considered it important to maintain the column order, it is an abstraction after all.  Why do you need it to be in a specific order?

Comment: We're dumping data into it in a specific order, and we can't change that, so we need the columns to be set in a specific order. It's not a big deal as it does look unchangeable, we'll just need to set the database up in the order we need the columns.

Comment: Since you are using symfony2 you can easily create commands to reorder.  Simply get the `EntityManager` from a `ContainerAwareCommand` and use `$em->getConnection()`.  Run SQL with `BEFORE` and `AFTER` to reorder the columns, you may need to do this every time you update the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use one of these methods on production

- Run app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql and run sql manualy
- Use migrations with DoctrineMigrationBundle or something like
  Liquibase

Comment: I already came to the conclusion of doing one of those, but I'm more interested in some kind of reasoning/rational as to why I'd need to do that, and why Doctrine wishes to alter the layout of my database to begin with. And, hopefully, there is another method to set an option to have it not do this. I do appreciate the input though.