# doctrine:schema:update doesn't respect column order

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this `Entity` in Symfony2 :

```
<?php

namespace Project\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="test", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $test;
}
```

I add the following line between {{userId}} and {{test}} :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="superbanana", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $superbanana;
```

Then I execute in console :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

It give me the response :

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD superbanana INT NOT NULL
```

**How can I do to have instead ? **

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD superbanana INT NOT NULL AFTER user_id
```

Comment: Doctrine does not handle field order (even for related fields, they will be always appended); If it's important to you and you don't have any data in tables before updating your schema run `php app/console doctrine:schema:drop` then run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to drop/create the table, you can use [@columnDefinition](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html) attribute and define the column definition yourself.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", columnDefinition="INT NOT NULL AFTER `user_id`")
 */
private $superbanana;
```

Comment: I don't think CREATE Supports AFTER

Comment: yes @Natdrip :  CREATE doesn't support AFTER but ALTER support AFTER

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because using Doctrine means that you don't care about how the Table is managed anymore (apparently someone [tried it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271468/symfony-doctrine-rearranging-database-columns) before).

And since you never use MySQL directly, I think there is no utility to specify column orders for Doctrine.

But you can always delete your table so Doctrine will completely rebuild the table, respecting your order.