# How to determine order of colums in table?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entities

I defined an Symfony2 entity class and I want to create the corresponding table in my database.  This works fine thanks to the command 'php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force'.

But the order of the columns isn't equal to the order in my class.  Any way to get them in the same order?

Comment: You could of course use --dump-sql and then hand edit the sql.  But quite frankly, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: You can specify `AFTER` statement in your entity definition. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148568/doctrineschemaupdate-doesnt-respect-column-order/24155527#24155527

Comment: I should work if you recreate the schema with doctrine:schema:drop --force` and `doctrine:schema:create` (assuming you have no non-fixture data you need to keep), but really why would you want/need to do something like that? I'm with @Cerad here.

Comment: Why is it that you want them to be the same order as in your entity? When doctrine calls up a record from your database it does it with named columns so they can be in any order on the database and it not be an issue.

Comment: @Darragh, I want de real columns in a certain order because i often need to inspect them. I know i can change the order manualy (eg. phpMyAdmin) but because tables are frequently rebuild that isn't an option.

Comment: @Darragh, I don't know why, but your sollution doctrine:schema:drop --force & doctrine:schema:create doesn't work.  This does not recreate the tables in same order as entity.  I even don't know how the column order in the new tables is defines.  Mistery...

Comment: Checking here, it appears Doctrine groups the FK columns and then orders the remaining columns by property order in the Entity. I assume that this is not featured behaviour though, so not consistent or to be relied on?