# set position of new entity property

Tags: symfony, doctrine, position, field

Let's say I have an old entity model, with many properties. Later, I want to add a new property, and update my database schema, with php app/console doctrine:schema:update

Can I choose between which database fields will be inserted this new field ?

I know I can "reset" doctrine fields position memory using php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata if I want to totally rebuild the table from scratch. But I want to keep my old data and just add a new field at a given position.

Comment: Could you answer this simple question: "For what?".

Comment: Funny how these questions tend to get repeated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283284/how-to-determine-order-of-colums-in-table  If only we had search capability.

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski : mainly for readability in phpMyAdmin. I prefer having my most important columns (the ones I check most often) at the begnning of the table. I'm probably not the only one.

Comment: @Cerad : thanks. found the accurate answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148568/doctrineschemaupdate-doesnt-respect-column-order/24155527#24155527